Does support of an inversion root of an X-reduced word always intersects complement of X?
Suppose that we have a Coxeter system $(W,S)$ with an associated reduced root system $R$ and let $X$ be a subset of $S$. Is it true that for any $(\varnothing,X)$-reduced word $w \in W$ support of an inversion root of $w$ always intersects $S\setminus X$?
This is true for $S_n$ and for classical affine root systems if $X=S\setminus${$v$} , where $v$ is an affine vertex, but the statement seems to be quite general. To be more concrete, I'm interested in the case when the Coxeter graph has weights $1$ on its edges.

So if anyone is still curious, I have a short argument due to Thomas Lam. Suppose that we have a root $\phi$ in $R_X^+$ - the set of positive roots with support in $X$. Then $\phi$ is an inversion root of some word $u$ from $W_X$ and all inversion roots $I(u)$ of $u$ are from $R_X^+$. Then we have
$$v=wu, l(v)=l(w)+l(u),$$
so $I(v)=u^{-1}I(w)\sqcup I(u)$.Now, since $vI(v)\subset R^-$ we have $wuI(u)\subset R^-$ and $uI(u)$ already lies in $R^-_X$. This shows that $wR_X^-\subset R^-$ and $wR^+_X\subset R^+$ which is equivalent to the original statement.
